# How to assign input string as a variable

Tags: php, string, variables, input

I don't know what it calls technically but here what I am trying achieve where user can insert one define word as a string from form text input than it should replace with defined variable.

Example:

```
$username = myfunction();
```

Now I want allow to user to enter one defined word like `username` in input field which will replace with $username variable.

So I want to use it for like `Contact to '.$username.'` So user can enter and change $username placement with that string keyword and they can play like `$username .'info'` etc.

Hope I explained properly and not in funny way.

Comment: @WebnetMobile.com, I will surely do that this weekend.

Comment: @deceze, I don't know how can I convert string to variable with str_replace as I know that is to replace the string only or can replace variable as well?

Comment: up vote for hint. Thanks a lot

Comment: Thanks a lot to who gave negative vote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to provide the user with a list of template variables like:

```
##USERNAME##
##ADDRESS##
etc.
```

that the user can use freely in the form. Then you can do a simple `str_replace` (that function takes arrays as arguments) to replace all template variables at once.

Your code would look something like:

```
$search = array('##USERNAME##', '##ADDRESS##', ...);
$replace = array($username, $address, ...);

$modified_text = str_replace($search, $replace, $original_text);
```